# Make a blog in magento and then assign that url in category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, blogs, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am a newbie in Magento. Yesterday, my sir gave me a project to integrate `blog feature into Magento. After I googled out for few mins, I found Magento blogs extension by aheadworks. It installed perfectly well with my Magento website and I made a few posts. I also made the setting in the blog in which I added  Route to blog option to  "blogs". Rewrite feature is enabled in my Magento website. I made a new category and named it as Blogs. In added url key I added "blogs" and saved it. It is showing me an empty product list in my Blogs menu. I also tried to add the customer URL rewrite with the help of [this site](http://commative.com/support/Magento_-_Customization/How_do_I_add_static_external_links_to_my_category_header_in_Ultimento_.html)

It is still showing me the same result.

```
The correct path of accessing the blog is :- www.mydomain.com/blogs

In frontend it is showing me :- www.mydomains.com/blogs.html
```

Any help would be appreciated the most.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i created a new empty category with name 'Infothek' and url_key infothek.html, and then replaced the url to the one the ahead works blog is using. In this special case it is done for the AheadWorks blog, but you can of course use this with any other/custom blog too.

1. Register a new Observer via config.xml for the frontend:

> ```
>    <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
>                     <observers>
>                 <add_blog_entry_to_topmenu>
>                     <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
>                     <method>changeTopMenu</method>
>                 </add_blog_entry_to_topmenu>
>             </observers>
>     </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
> ```

1. Implement the observer method

> ```
> public function changeTopMenu($observer){
>     $event = $observer->getEvent();
>     $menu = $event->getMenu();
>     $menuCollection = $menu->getChildren();
>     foreach ($menuCollection as $menuItem) {
>       if ($menuItem->getData('name') == 'Infothek'){
>         $blogPath = Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/blog/route');
>         $menuItem->setUrl(str_replace('infothek.html', $blogPath,$menuItem->getUrl()));
>      }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change url write for specific category.

As here i am giving your detail [Documentation link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules)

for url write to category

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: i have done that thing. I made a new rewrite url by selecting the category -"Blog" and then saved it After that i have made a custom url rewrite and added the id, requsted path taken from the blog categoryrewrite url and in target path i have written the target path of my blog extension url but still it is not working. :(

Comment: Yup did it and also reindexed it too but still the result remains the same :(

Comment: Which version are you running? Magento made changes to the way data is indexed and url rewrites are handled to improve performance in the last version. This also introduced the problem that categories are now available through /<category_key>.html and just /<category_key> instead of only the .html version by default. This resulted in an overlap with frontName url's of modules. During Magento's routing steps the category will always be matched prior to the module, rendering it impossible to have category with the same 'key' as a frontName of a module.

Comment: I am using magento version 1.7

Comment: If blog/index/index is still working (still obviously depends whether controller/action does exist), then it might be the same issue.